# Filter data using frequency model

Tags: matlab

I would like to filter my time vector `v` using a given frequency response.
The Filer is given as a set of two vectors: `f` and `h`, where f is the frequency and h is the magnitude of the response.
I cannot `fft` my data `v` and then multiply in the frequency domain, since my data `v` is extremely large and `fft`ing it is not feasible.
I've tried Yule-walker approach, but it doesn't fit to my data.

How can I apply this given frequency response on the data?

Comment: Can you provide some code samples?  How big are you talking?  Matlab can handle really large arrays, at least 1e7 pretty easily.  Could you break up your time ranges into a few pieces?

Comment: How "large" are we talking here?

Comment: 1 giga samples   (size 1x1,000,000,000,000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could try a linear phase FIR filter. You can design such a filter to achieve your desired frequency response, then filter your data using it.

Let me first generate some hypothetical `f`, `h`, and `v` so that my solution contains a working example:

```
n = 20;                  % (desired filter order)/2
Fs = 50;                 % Data sampling rate
f = (0:n)'/n * (Fs/2);   % Freq for filter response
h = (f < 10);            % Hypothetical low-pass filter
t = (0:1000)'/Fs;
v = sin(t) + sin(2*pi*20*t);  % Hypothetical data
```

## Design an FIR filter using `ifft`

You can inverse Fourier transform the filter's frequency response to obtain FIR filter coefficients.

Here, I am assuming that `f` is evenly spaced, starts at 0, and ends at the Nyquist frequency. If this is not the case, then maybe you can interpolate `f` and `h` so that this is true. Also keep in mind that the resulting filter will have a length of `2*n`, where `n = length(f)-1`

Since we are assuming a symmetric real filter, the filter should have the same response for negative frequencies. `ifft` expects the frequencies to start at zero, though, so these negative frequency responses get aliased into higher frequencies. Assuming that `h` is a column vector:

```
h_shifted = [h; flipud(h(2:end-1))];
```

Then we inverse transform this and shift it back:

```
b_shifted = ifft(h_shifted);
b = [b_shifted(n+1:end); b_shifted(1:n)];
```

If you have the Signal Processing Toolbox, you can also try `designfilt` which gives you a few more options with regards to filter design.

## Filter your data

Now that you have your filter coefficients, you can use `filter` or `fftfilt` to apply this filter to your data. Remember to account for the filter delay. For example:

```
v_padded = [v; zeros(n,1)];
y_padded = fftfilt(b, v_padded);
y = y_padded(n+1:end);
```

Of course, if you are filtering the data in blocks, you should pad with the subsequent data instead of with zeros :)

Comment: How can I print the spectral power of the new coefficients? I would like to compare the evaluation to the original requirment.

Comment: If you have the Signal Processing Toolbox, `fvtool` is pretty nice. Otherwise you can Fourier Transform the filter coefficients. Keep in mind that this design will exactly match at the design points (`f` and `h`) so you will want to run the `fft` at a higher order to see what happens in between. e.g. `N_fft = pow2(nextpow2(n)+4); semilogy((0:N_fft-1)'/N_fft * Fs, abs(fft(b, N_fft)));`